# can't add item to JcomboBox Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I am having issues adding items to a JcomboBox (Swing) in Java. I have no errors, but something is not working since the function does not add any items. I simply want to add 4 courses (their courseName) to different slots in the comboBox. The constructor should add the elements. Can someone identify what I am doing wrong?

Here are the important parts of my code.

```
public class CourseCatalog extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     ArrayList <Course> courseList = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addCourse(Course accAdd) {
    courseList.add(accAdd);
}

/**
 * Creates new form ViewKursFrame
 */
public CourseCatalog() {
    initComponents();

    for (Course kursen : courseList){
        jcbKursNamn.addItem(kursen.getCourseName());
        System.out.println("sjAJDJASJD");
    }
}
```

Course class

```
public class Course {

private String kursnamn;
private String Kurskod;
private String svårighetsgrad;
private String ämnesgrupp;
//static ArrayList <Course> kursLista = new ArrayList<>();

public Course(){   }

public Course (String kursnamn, String kurskod, String svårighetsgrad, String ämnesgrupp){
    this.kursnamn = kursnamn;
    this.Kurskod = kurskod;
    this.ämnesgrupp = ämnesgrupp;
    this.svårighetsgrad = svårighetsgrad;
}
```

Main class

```
public class MainView {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CourseCatalog view = new CourseCatalog();
    Course kurs1 = new Course("Programutveckling med java", "D0024E", "Grundkurs", "Data");
    Course kurs2 = new Course("Programutveckling med java2", "D0007N", "Grundkurs", "Data");
    Course kurs3 = new Course("Programutveckling med Ruby", "D0024F", "Masterkurs", "Data");
    Course kurs4 = new Course("Programutveckling med HTML", "D004F", "Grundkurs", "Data");

    view.addCourse (kurs1);
    view.addCourse (kurs2);
    view.addCourse (kurs3);
    view.addCourse (kurs4);

    view.visaKurserna();
    view.setVisible(true);       
}
```

Comment: Where's the `JComboBox`? Is it `jcbKursNamn`?

Comment: @achAmháin I am using Jframe so it is drag and drop. the code for the comboBox is auto generated. When I run the program I see the JComboBox + 4 "items" which are generated by default.

Comment: Please post [mcve] so we do not have to guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is you are adding courses to the JComboBox in the **CourseCatalog** constructor. As any class's constructor always gets called only while the object is being initialized and at that initialization time **courseList** variable you are maintaining to hold list of courses would be empty - causing your JComboBox not showing anything.

**Fix/Resolution :**
Instead of adding courses to the JComboBox in the time of initializing add it while adding courses. 
Have your addCourse() method like below:

```
public void addCourse(Course accAdd) {
    courseList.add(accAdd);
    jcbKursNamn.addItem(accAdd.getCourseName());
}
```

I hope this answer helps

Comment: Thanks a lot @Udaya Shankara Gandhi Thalabat
It sure did!

Comment: can you +1 my answer if it helps you

Comment: I tried but I have to low reputation apperantly. @Udaya Shankara Gandhi Thalabat. 

Update: Oh nvm, it is still recorded. Just now shown =) 
Thanks again